# C++: using const string reference as constructor argument

Tags: c++, eclipse, string

In eclipse, it gives me no problem, when I try to compile from terminal with g++, it says something like

MyClass.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to `MyClass2::MyClass2(int, std::basic_string, std::allocator >, int, int, double)'

for a line where I simply pass a quoted string line "thisValue" for the constructor argument. If the type of the argument is changed into regular string, it's fine, but when I do const string& instead, g++ complains, and eclipse doesn't. How come?

Comment: You'll have to show some code.  I suspect your declaration and implementation differ.

Comment: Nope, they don't. Otherwise, how can eclipse make sense out of it, but not g++ when I run make in terminal?

Comment: "undefined reference" means a linker error. If it works in Eclipse, then the problem is likely in your build commands/Makefile. Post the commands you use to build your project.

Comment: But why does it work when the arg is defined as string, and not for const string& ?

Comment: Is it possible that it doesn't know how to implicitly convert const char* to const string& ?